# (Azure) MySQL: MySQL Server Has Gone Away

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo, azure-sql-database

Following the [guide on Azure,](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connectivity-issues/) [configuring the firewall settings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/), I am still unable to access my MySQL database.  I get the following from ALL servers, even if the IP address is whitelisted:

> PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\Users\admin\app\dbtest.php on line 3 PHP
>   Warning:  PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet.
>   PID=11692 in C:\Users\admin\app\dbtest.php on line
>   3
>
> Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\Users\admin\app\dbtest.php on line 3
>
> Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet.
>   PID=11692 in C:\Users\admin\app\dbtest.php on line
>   3 Error connecting to SQL Server.PDOException Object (
>       [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>       [string:Exception:private] => 
>       [code:protected] => 2006
>       [file:protected] => C:\Users\admin\app\dbtest.php
>       [line:protected] => 3
>       [trace:Exception:private] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => Array
>                   (
>                       [file] => C:\Users\admin\app\dbtest.php
>                       [line] => 3
>                       [function] => __construct
>                       [class] => PDO
>                       [type] => ->
>                       [args] => Array
>                           (
>                               [0] => mysql:dbname=mydb;host=app.database.windows.net;port=1433
>                               [2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/) => admin
>                               [2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/) => pass
>                           )
>                   )
>           )
>       [previous:Exception:private] => 
>       [errorInfo] =>  ) 1 Process finished with exit code 0

Here is my PHP script to connect:

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=db;host=app.database.windows.net;port=1433", "admin", "pass");

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

What are general connection settings required to connect to an Azure MySQL database without the connection timing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database endpoint in such format `app.database.windows.net;port=1433` is the endpoint of Azure SQL which provides the SQL Server service. Not MySQL. Please try to install the SQL Server driver for windows at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098. And then try to use `new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=AdventureWorks", "{user}", "{pass}");` to connect to Azure SQL.

If you want to use MySQL BaaS on Azure, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/ for detailed steps.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.